# What is the the easiest way to execute SQL queries on a SQL dump file?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to execute a query on a .sql dump file **without** importing it into a database?

Example: stuff.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `options` (
...

INSERT INTO `options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES
(1, 'siteurl', 'http://www.someurl.com', 'yes'),
...
```

Then execute some `SELECT` Statement to get the options data.

Sure, I could import the dump in a local DB, execute what I want, dump it again and delete the DB again, but is there a way with less overhead?

Comment: Only by writing them as command and not using `use tbl_name; source some.sql`

Comment: NO it is not possible!

Comment: I was searching for this before but I didn't got any solution, people say its not allowed because of security

Comment: you mean like this `mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without importing at all, I dont think so. However you have other options. You could import your SQL dump into a temporary memory-only database, then query that database. For instance this could be an SQLite `:MEMORY:` database if your sql is compatible, or you could use `Engine=MEMORY` (or `Engine=HEAP` for older versions) with MySQL "`create table`" DDL to create a memory table, and then query that db (You would have to replace Engine=INNODB or Engine=MyISAM with MEMORY in your dump file to import it). Same idea.

Obviously, this depends on size of your data you want to query. a 1TB Database would probably prove impractical to import into RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
Process p = null;
            try {
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                p = runtime.exec("mysqldump -uroot -pdbpass --add-drop-database -B dbname -r " + "filepath" + "Filename" + ".sql");
//change the dbpass and dbname with your dbpass and dbname
                int processComplete = p.waitFor();

                if (processComplete == 0) {

                    System.out.println("Backup created successfully!");

                } else {
                    lblMessage.setText("Could not create the backup");
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```